# When building a json api for a model with a belongs_to association, the whitelisted attributes of that association are ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activemodel, active-model-serializers

I'm building a json api for my model, `User` and a `User belongs_to :role`. Even though I have already build a json api for `Role` and whitelisted the attributes I wanted to include, the whitelisted attributes are ignored whenever I visit a `user#show` action.

In my `RoleSerializer` file, I have specified that only two attributes can be accessed: `:id`, and `:name`. When I go to the 'roles#show' action, this works fine and renders only these two attributes.

**/roles/1.json**

```
{"role":{"id":1,"name":"Admin"}}
```

However, this json response is not used for the `user#show` json response. It keeps tacking on the `created_at` and `updated_at` attribute, which I don't want.

**/users/1.json**

```
{ 
  "user": { 
      "id": 1,
      "email": "dietz.72@osu.edu",
      "name_n": "dietz.72", 
      "first_name": "Peter", 
      "last_name": "Dietz",
      "role": {  
          "created_at": "2013-08-08T00:21:56Z",
          "id":1,
          "name": "Admin",
          "updated_at": "2013-08-08T00:21:56Z" } } }
```

I've tried multiple ways of listing the `:role` attribute in `user_serializer.rb` including the following code below. Unfortunately, this does not work.

**user_serializer.rb**

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :email, :name_n, :first_name, :last_name

  # I also tried attributes :role
  attribute :role, serializer: RoleSerializer
end
```

**users_controller.rb - show action**

```
def show
  @user = User.where(id: params[:id]).first

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: users }
  end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :emplid, :name_n, :first_name, :last_name

  belongs_to :role
  has_many :agreements, foreign_key: "student_id"
  has_many :forms, through: :agreements, foreign_key: "student_id"

  def active_model_serializer
    UserSerializer
  end
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from this fine gentleman from the issue queue of ActiveModelSerializer's github page:
https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/371#issuecomment-22363620

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :email, :name_n, :first_name, :last_name

  has_one :role, serializer: RoleSerializer
end
```

---

So, even though there is a `User belongs_to :role` association in the controller, using `has_one` association utilizes the ActiveModel Serializer and gives me only the attributes I want.